# Lubuntu 16.04 32-bit can't load ldlinux.c32 when booting from a flash drive on a Gateway (HV) MFATXPNT ESX 500S P04 from 2003

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Target computer has a functional but slow install of Windows XP already on it.
Target computer's hard drive might not be in the best health.
Flash drive was created on a different, more modern computer running Windows 10.

I have no idea what I should try next. This is my first time doing this.

Update at bottom!

### BIOS Setup

```
Main

    BIOS Version               RG84510A.15A.0021.P11

    Processor Type             Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4
    Processor Speed            2.40 GHz
    System Bus Speed           533 MHz
    System Memory Speed        266 MHz

    Cache RAM                  512 KB

    Total Memory               2047 MB
    Memory Bank 0              1024 MB (DDR266)
    Memory Bank 1              1024 MB (DDR266)

    Language                   [English]

    System Time                [18:03:47]
    System Date                [Tue 07/24/2018]

Advanced

    Setup Warning:
    Setting items on this screen to incorrect values
    may cause your system to malfunction!

    ► Boot Configuration

      Numlock                    [On]
      ISA Enable Bit             [Enabled]

    ► Peripheral Configuration

      Serial Port A              [Enabled]
        Base I/O Address         [3F8]
        Interrupt                [IRQ 4]
      Parallel Port              [Enabled]
        Mode                     [ECP]
        Base I/O Address         [378]
        Interrupt                [IRQ 7]
        DMA                      [3]

      Audio                      [Enabled]
      LAN Device                 [Enabled]

    ► IDE Configuration

      IDE Controller             [Both]
      PCI IDE Bus Master         [Enabled]
      Hard Disk Pre-Delay        [Disabled]

      ► Primary IDE Master     : [Maxtor 2F040J0        ]

        Drive Installed            Maxtor 2F040J0
        Type                       [Auto]
        Maximum Capacity           41.1GB

        Configuration Options Selected By BIOS

        LBA Mode  :                Supported
        Block Mode:                16 Sectors
        PIO Mode  :                Mode 4
        Ultra DMA :                Mode 5
        Cable Detected :           80 Conductor


        NOTE:  The actual performance of the drive
        is dependent upon the Operating System and
        IDE Drivers.

      ► Primary IDE Slave      : [Not Detected]
      ► Secondary IDE Master   : [HL-DT-ST RW/DVD GCC-43]

        Drive Installed            HL-DT-ST RW/DVD GCC4320
        Type                       [Auto]

        Configuration Options Selected By BIOS

        LBA Mode  :                Supported
        PIO Mode  :                Mode 4
        Ultra DMA :                Mode 2
        Cable Detected :           40 Conductor


        NOTE:  The actual performance of the drive
        is dependent upon the Operating System and
        IDE Drivers

      ► Secondary IDE Slave    : [Not Detected]

    ► Diskette Configuration

      Diskette Controller        [Enabled]

      Floppy A                   [1.44 MB 3½"]

      Diskette Write Protect     [Disabled]

    ► Event Log Configuration

      Event Log                  [Space Available]

      View Event Log

      Clear Event Log
      Event Logging              [Enabled]


      Mark Events As Read

    ► Video Configuration

      Primary Video Adapter      [AGP]

    ► USB Configuration

      High-Speed USB             [Enabled]
      Legacy USB Support         [Enabled]

      USB ZIP Emulation Type     [Auto]

Security

    Supervisor Password :      Not Installed
    User Password       :      Not Installed

    Set Supervisor Password
    Set User Password

Power

    ► ACPI
      Advanced Configuration and Power Interface

      ACPI Suspend State         [S3 State]
      Video Repost               [No]


    After Power Failure        [Stay Off]

    Wake on PCI PME            [Stay Off]

Boot

    Silent Boot                [Disabled]
    Intel(R) Rapid BIOS Boot   [Disabled]
    PXE Boot to LAN            [Disabled]
    USB Boot                   [Enabled]

    ► Boot Device Priority

      1st Boot Device            [ATAPI CD-ROM]
      2nd Boot Device            [Removable Dev.]
      3rd Boot Device            [Hard Drive]

    ► Hard Disk Drives

      1st Hard Disk Drive        [SanDisk Cruzer Blade]
      2nd Hard Disk Drive        [Maxtor 2F040J0]

    ► Removable Devices

      1st Removable Device       [1st FLOPPY DRIVE]

    ► ATAPI CD-ROM Drives

      1st ATAPI CDROM            [HL-DT-ST RW/DVD GCC-43]


    Display Setup Prompt       [Yes]
    Keyboard Detection Warning [Enabled]
    Mouse Detection Warning    [Enabled]
    CD/DVD Detection Warning   [Enabled]
    Hard Drive Detect. Warning [Enabled]
    Hard Drive Self Diagnostic [Enabled]

Exit

    Exit Saving Changes
    Exit Discarding Changes
    Load Optimal Defaults
    Load Custom Defaults
    Save Custom Defaults
    Discard Changes
```

### What I've Tried

Rufus 3.1:

```
SYSLINUX 6.03 CHS 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al

Failed to load ldlinux.c32
Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue.
_
```

Universal USB Installer 1.9.8.2:

```
SYSLINUX 4.07 CHS 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et al
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot: _
```

#### Update:

LiveUSB Install 2.5.12 (also attempted install from old computer):

```
Boot Error
_
```

Short version: All installs work on modern computer. Target computer is not having any of it.

#### Update 2:

Fat16 + UUI:

```
SYSLINUX 4.07 CHS 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et al
Could not find kernel image: /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
boot: _
```

#### Update 3:

Drives created with DD mode in Rufus are NOT seen as bootable devices by this particular BIOS. Neither are burned DVDs.

## Update 4, The Finale! (for now)

I've done it! I've finally got a version of Linux to boot on this machine after a week of fighting and 3 [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/90qp7b/how_do_i_create_an_installation_drive_for_lubuntu/) for [help](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/90u2b4/need_help_with_booting_from_usb/) (4 [if you count the one where I asked for distro recommendations](https://www.reddit.com/r/computers/comments/908pdb/which_linux_distro_should_i_use_for_this_computer/)).

I was in bed thinking "hmmmm... the BIOS only lists CD-ROM as a boot device, maybe if I manage to get a distro that will fit on a CD (700 MB) I might be able to boot from it." I had to go back all the way to Lubuntu 14.04 but I loaded it on to a CD and... IT FREAKING BOOTS TO THE INSTALLATION MENU!!!!! VICTORY!!! (pardon my excitement)

I now have Lubuntu 14.04 running in trial mode as I backup everything on the hard drive to a flash drive. I would like to get a more recent version running on this thing (14.04 is from 2014!) so that's why I'm leaving this ask still unanswered. If anyone manages to suggest something that works for newer versions of Lubuntu, you will have my respect.

Comment: Have you considered getting something a bit newer?

Comment: On such old systems you can try to use internal CD/DVD drive, USB-CD/DVD, or PXE-boot. Other possible option is to try booting from 32-bit Gparted Live (it boots on Prescots and Irwindale, I checked). Other method - is to move hard-drive to the other (modern) system, install Ubuntu here, then move hard-drive back to P4 system. You may consider to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE here.

Comment: Have you ruled out that the ISO you used to create the bootable disk with is bad?  Did you verify the ISO had the proper checksums?